# What are some adaptive machine learning techniques that cater for data that may change slightly but is still correct?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, online-algorithms, domain-adaptation

Are there suitable machine learning techniques that may be applied to a continual stream of data and update its models for data that it believes to be different to the most representative case but still correct?

If so, under what scenarios would some be particularly useful?

Comment: This is the problem which "online learning" attempts to solve. It's a large area of study.